# What is the difference in declaring attributes in the constructor in the below 3 ways?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, attributes

```
def __init__(self):
    self.score=[]

def __init__(self,score=[]):
    self.score=score

def __init__(self,score):
    self.score=[]
```

Can you please explain what happens behind the scenes? TIA.

Comment: The third one is somewhat pointless, as it produces the same result as the first. The second is (probably) a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: There are no attribute declarations in Python. In any event, this is irrelevant that they happen to be `__init__` methods, this is just asking what the difference is between  different kinds of parameters...

Answer (score 3):

```
def init(self):
    self.score=[]
```

`self.score` is always initialized to an empty list.

```
def init(self,score=[]):
    self.score=score
```

The caller can pass in an optional list parameter. If they don't, `self.score` is initialized to an empty list once, when the function is defined. (See [Common Gotchas: Mutable Default Arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) for why this is a bad idea.)

```
def init(self,score):
    self.score=[]
```

The caller must pass in a list parameter (normally, that would be assigned to `self.score`, but you're throwing that value out and setting `self.score` to an empty list). The third example probably should be:

```
def init(self, score):
    self.score = score
```

Comment: "If they don't, self.score is initialized to an empty list." strictly speaking, not true. It is initialized to the object that is the default parameter. It may or may not be an empty list, if that object gets mutated, for example. Mutable default arguments are dangerous if you don't know how they work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right. I always forget about this when the IDE doesn't warn me. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The "score" member is always set to []
2. You have the option to specify what you want to set the member "score" to.
3. You have to specify "score" while constructing the object. The difference to 2. is, that here you **have** to specify it, while in 2. it's optional, and you're just setting a default

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, you always assign [] to the objects score variable.
In the second one, you can construct the object with or without the score value, for example if you do obj = object([1,2,3]), then it will have score equal to [1,2,3], but you can also call it without the score argument, like obj = object(), and it will have score equal to [].
In the third example, you have to create with the score argument, but it will be ignored, as it is not assigned to the self.score variable.

Answer (score 0):

`score` in function header is a local variable

```
def init(self,score):
```

and here it is an instance attribute

```
self.score=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and last methods have exactly the same effect: assign an empty list to the instance attribute `score`.  For some strange reason, the third one requires an extra positional parameter `score`, which is not used.

The middle one creates and reserves a default value for the parameter `score`; at parse time, this value is an empty list.  Any instantiation that omits that argument gets assigned the reserved list.  The danger here is that these instantiations will all refer to the *same* list: a change to the `score` attribute in one will be reflected in *all* of the other objects that used the default value.